# Recursive query or loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. First, Tab1, has two columns. Material and quantity (column material without duplicities). It says current quantity of material on the warehouse. The table looks like:

| Material | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| mat1 | 500 |
| mat2 | 400 |
| mat3 | 600 |
| mat4 | 100 |
| ... | ... |
| and so on... |  |

Second table, Tab2, has three columns. Date, Material and quantity. Sort by date. It says when each material will be needed  and also with needed quantity to production. The table is look like:

| Date | Material | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-28 | mat1 | 250 |
| 2023-03-01 | mat2 | 100 |
| 2023-03-02 | mat4 | 50 |
| 2023-03-04 | mat3 | 500 |
| 2023-03-05 | mat1 | 200 |
| 2023-03-08 | mat2 | 350 |
| 2023-03-10 | mat1 | 200 |
| 2023-03-12 | mat3 | 50 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| and so on... |  |  |

Both tables are live (lets say view tables) and so the data will be added in time

I need a query, that will show me the date, when warehouse quantity for each material will be out of stock (So the quantity will be totaled from "row to row" and when the sum of quantity overflowed the warehouse stock of the material, the query return the date value -  So mat1 will be out of stock 2023-03-10 and mat2 will be out of stock 2023-03-08). I find some LOOP queries and "CTE" queries, but I was not able to construct any of them. I think, some kind of recursive query will be needed. Is there any like recursive query? Or do I need somehing else?

Comment: Seems you don't need either; a cumulative `SUM` should be all you need, and probably a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to write a recursive query for that purpose. Here's a nonrecursive query:

```
select min(tab2.Date), tab1.Material
from tab1
join tab2
on tab1.Material = tab2.Material
where tab1.Quantity < (
    select sum(temp.Quantity)
    from tab2 temp
    where temp.Date <= tab2.Date and
          temp.Material = tab1.Material
)
group by tab1.Material;
```

**Explanation**:

- we load pairs of `tab1` and `tab2`
- grouped by `tab1.Material` to make sure that we can get the earliest `Date` for each `Material`
- the (`tab1`, `tab2`) tuples are of course paired by `Material`
- where the total `Quantity` of the material is lesser than the `sum` of the `Quantity` of material of the same type used up to that date

**Result**:

- we get a list of `min(tab2.Date), tab1.Material`
- representing the earliest `Date` for each `Material` when it gets out of stock

**Observation**: The current implementation lists the first date when there is a need for more material (of each type) than needed. If, instead you need to get the first date when the quantity will be 0 or less, then change the `<` in the main operand of the `where` clause to `<=`.

Dample Data

```
create table tab1(
  Material VARCHAR(32),
  Quantity INT
);

create table tab2(
  Date Date,
  Material VARCHAR(32),
  Quantity INT
);

insert into tab1(Material, Quantity) values
('a', 13),
('b', 14),
('c', 15);

insert into tab2(Date, Material, Quantity) values
('2023-01-01', 'a', 8),
('2023-01-01', 'b', 8),
('2023-01-01', 'c', 8),
('2023-01-02', 'a', 6),
('2023-01-02', 'b', 6),
('2023-01-02', 'c', 6),
('2023-01-03', 'a', 1),
('2023-01-03', 'b', 1),
('2023-01-03', 'c', 1);
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c3af07/1

[image]

Notice that in my example, **c** does not appear at all in the result, because, even though it ends up having a 0 `Quantity`, it will never get below it.

Comment: That looks as what I need. But I cant understand the temp section. What is differnce between tab2 and temp? Where are the data for the temp table?

Comment: @JanJanoušek They are representing the same `tab2` table's records, but in different roles. This is why the second is aliased as `temp`, so we can unambiguously refer the field of each. So, the first `temp2` represents the date when the material gets out of stock (because of the where and the group by clause's specification), whereas the subquery uses `tab2` as well, aliased as `temp`, representing the records of earlier dates than the record(s) of `tab2` in the outer query. Notice that in the subquery we specify what `temp` is based on `tab1` and `tab2` of the outer query.

Comment: @JanJanoušek if there are further unclarities, please feel free to ask any questions. When the solution becomes fully clear, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Wow. I adjust it to my whole dataand it is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data you've given us, it seems all you need is a cumulative `SUM` and a CTE so you can filter on when the remaining quantity is less than or equal to zero:

```sql
WITH Cumulative AS(
    SELECT T2.Date,
           T2.Material,
           SUM(T2.quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.Material ORDER BY Date) AS quantity,
           T1.quantity - SUM(T2.quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.Material ORDER BY Date) AS Remaining
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'20230228'),'mat1',250),
                (CONVERT(date,'20230301'),'mat2',100),
                (CONVERT(date,'20230302'),'mat4',50),
                (CONVERT(date,'20230304'),'mat3',500),
                (CONVERT(date,'20230305'),'mat1',200),
                (CONVERT(date,'20230308'),'mat2',350),
                (CONVERT(date,'20230310'),'mat1',200),
                (CONVERT(date,'20230312'),'mat3',50))T2(Date,Material,quantity)
         JOIN (VALUES('mat1',500),
                     ('mat2',400),
                     ('mat3',600),
                     ('mat4',100))T1 (Material,quantity) ON T2.Material = T1.Material)
SELECT Date,
       Material,
       Remaining
       --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Material ORDER BY Remaining DESC) AS RN
FROM Cumulative
WHERE Remaining <= 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to mention that the data in Tab2 will grow over time, it is a live table. So just the list of entry will not be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are stating there, @JanJanoušek . If your sample data isn't representative of your actual problem, you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75507974/edit) your question to make it so it is; I can't make a solution based on data I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to get what you wants. see the following query as an example:

```
WITH usage as (
SELECT
    Date,
        Material,
        SUM(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY Material order by Date) as usage_up_to_date
FROM
       TAB2
),
stock_balance AS (
SELECT
      usage.Date,
      usage.Material,
      (TAB1.quantity - usage.usage_up_to_date) as balance
FROM
      usage
JOIN
      TAB1
ON
       usage.Material = TAB1.Material 
)
SELECT
      Material,
      MIN(Date) AS Date
FROM
     stock_balance
WHERE
      balance <=0
GROUP BY
     Material
```